# Displaying PDF files on Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want load and display PDF files. These files are in a listview and I want display a selected PDF file. This is the code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    private ListView mainListView ;  
        private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  
    String filepath;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstactivity);
            mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  
            final ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();  
        final File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(storage,"/Folder/");
        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                for (String s : file.list()) {
                    sb.append(s + " ");
        List.addAll( Arrays.asList(s) );
                }
            }

            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView,List); 
            mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                    String filepath = new File("/Folder/"+ List.get(arg2)).getAbsolutePath();
                     File file = new File(filepath);
                    openPdfIntent(file);


                }


            });
        }
        private void openPdfIntent(File file) {
               Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

                            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            try {
                                startActivity(pdfIntent);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
     }
```

This code doesn't work. The logcat error is : "java.lang.NullPointerException". 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and please indicate what lines in that stack trace are lines from your source code shown above. We have no good way to know what line is the one that is generating the `NullPointerException` otherwise.

Comment: `String filepath = new File("/Folder/"+ List.get(arg2)).getAbsolutePath();`, this line is wrong

Comment: How can I indicate a selected file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code pls:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("path-to-document"));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (activities.size() > 0) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // Do something else here. Maybe pop up a Dialog or Toast
}
```

Comment: PackageManager and List cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: PackageManager is an android class:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Comment: ResolveInfo is an Android class to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html You only need to import them

Answer (score 0):

Acccording to me the error you are getting is because of the incorrect path of the file, just specifying     "/Folder/" will return null pointer exception.
Try something like

```
       String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/FolderName/"+"File name in list"
```

Comment: but the path file is written well because I used it in another app and it works. how can I get the file from the path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  example,old type but code is  perfect 
http://www.edumobile.org/android/pdf-list-example/